# How to fetch apigee data into onsen ui list

Tags: jquery, cordova, apigee, onsen-ui

I made a web application which searches for nearby pharmacies. These locations are stored at Apigee within a data collection.

Updates of the (static) Google Map is no problem but to put the retrieved data in a proper onsen ui list (ons-list) unfortunately is.

Snippet of the code used:

```
<ons-list class="list" id="list" data-role="listview">
</ons-list>

$('#list').bind('pageinit', function() {
   $('#list').listview('refresh');
});

$('<ons-list-item class="list__item--tappable list__item__line-height
    modifier="chevron">'+label+' - '+store.get('name')+'</ons-list-item>').appendTo("#list");
```

Currently my result set is put in one line. Source after fetching data from apigee:

```
<ons-list class="list ons-list-inner" id="list" data-role="listview">
    <ons-list-item class="list__item--tappable list__item__line-height" modifier="chevron">Pharmacy 1</ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item class="list__item--tappable list__item__line-height" modifier="chevron">Pharmacy 2</ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
```

Result of the last stated looks fine if I put it in static.

So... What's going wrong here?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure that I understand your question – however, it looks like (since I can't see all of your code) that you might be running into a simple race condition. In other words, you are refreshing the list on 'pageinit', however at that point, the data has not been returned from the BaaS. You need to call .listview('refresh') AFTER the loop that appends the list items has completed. For example:

```
YourCollectionName.fetch(function (err, data) {
    if (err) { //do something } else {
        while (YourCollectionName.hasNextEntity()) {
            var store = YourCollectionName.getNextEntity();
            $('<ons-list-item class="list__item--tappable list__item__line-height
    modifier="chevron">'+label+' - '+store.get('name')+'</ons-list-item>').appendTo("#list");
}
$('#list').listview('refresh');
});
```

Notice that the iteration happens, appending to the list for as long as there are items in the collection and THEN, the refresh happens.